# Using .htaccess to serve root domain content from subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP app that requires the domain's document root to be set to `/(wherever)/app_dir/www` for it to run successfully (which can't be changed, sadly). Unfortunately, on my host I can't change the document root for the main `mydomain.com` (from `/public_html` to `/public_html/app_dir/www` but I *can* edit the document root for subdomains.

Subdomains are stored in `/public_html/subdomain.domain.com`, and setting the root for the subdomain to `/public_html/subdomain.domain.com/app_dir/www` allows the app to display its content just fine at `http://subdomain.domain.com/`.

In order to have its content appear at the root domain (where I can't install it since the document root is uneditable), I'm trying use .htaccess to serve content from the subdomain without redirecting the browser, so going to `www.domain.com` will show `www.domain.com` in the location bar, but actually be serving the contents of `subdomain.domain.com` (and likewise with `www.domain.com/something` pulling instead from `subdomain.domain.com/something`).

As I understand it, mod_proxy should be able to do it (and is installed). Based on other SO answers to similar queries, this looks like it should be the solution:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(www.)?domain\.com$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,P]
```

I've been trying it with a simple index.html dummy in place of anything more complex, but either my syntax is off (I've tried several variations, without joy, including without the P option; I'm no expert and my previous .htaccess experience is limited to simple rewrites and 301 redirects), I've missed something blindingly obvious, or I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely, because I just get the dummy index file I've got at the root domain instead of the equally dummy index file sitting in the subdomain's root (which displays just fine if you go to `subdomain.domain.com`, but that's not the aim).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What PHP app is it? I don't think you need all that.

Comment: Second Crack: https://github.com/marcoarment/secondcrack

Comment: I don't see anything that would stop you from using it on `public_html`.

Comment: SC does run in public_html. If you install it there, though, `www.domain.com` becomes a directory listing and you don't get actual HTML until you get to the front page at `www.domain.com/secondcrack/www` (which could then be rewritten to remove the /secondcrack/www part after a redirect from `www.domain.com`), but page links it creates are in the form `www.domain.com/year/month/day/slug` which generates a 404 error; they need the app path to work but don't include it because SC assumes it's installed below the doc root.

Comment: To fix I'd have to redirect generated links, then hide the app path, or else dig around in the code and fix URL gen there and again rewrite them so the app path's hidden.

Installing to a subdomain and then serving it up like it's coming from the primary domain seems simpler if it can be made to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This rule is wrong and faulty, it doesn't do what you believe it should be doing:

```
RewriteRule ^(www.)?domain\.com$ http://subdomain.domain.com/$1 [L,P]
```

**Remember `RewriteRule` matches just the `REQUEST_URI` without domain and query string parts.**

If mod_proxy is enabled you can have this rule instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://subdomain.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [P,L]
```

If for some reason mod_proxy is not enabled them please let me know, I will suggest an alternative solution.